# Can I unlock different characters?

Tags: kung-fury-street-rage

I've just started playing the game, but I've noticed that in addition to Kung Fury, there are other characters from the movie standing in the background:

[image]

Why are they standing there at the start of the game? Is there a way I can play as them or unlock them somehow?